# Migrating Coffescript to ES2015 code (Meteor code)

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am migrating some code from Coffescript to ES2015. I would like the result of a transpile to look like this:

```
Meteor.users.deny({
  update: function() {
    return true;
  }
});
```

In Coffescript, this does it:

```
Meteor.users.deny
    update: ->
        true
```

Is it possible to code this in ES2015 so that the output matches the original code?

Addendum:

This is what I tried on [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) with Evaluate checked

```
   Meteor.users.deny({
         update: function () {
              return true;
         }
    });
```

and

```
Meteor.users.deny({
      update: () => true
});
```

both of which output:

```
Meteor.users.deny({
     update: function update() {
          return true;
     }
});
```

The anonymous function becomes named (update)

So why is this a "problem"? I am trying to understand ES2105 and something I could easily do in Coffeescript does not seem possible in ES2015. I was trying to confirm that - or see if I was misusing ES2015 or missing a capability of it

[This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226150/how-to-ignore-a-block-of-code-when-transpiling-with-babeljs) but does solve what I am trying to do. Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: What ES6 code did you try that did not work? Please show us your attempts (and your babel flags).

Comment: Your first snippet already is valid ES6 code that will transpile to exactly that. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You cannot avoid the function from being named in ES6. If you evaluate such a method definition in an ES6 engine, it will produce a named function, and that's what Babel is trying to reproduce. Have a look at http://www.2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html

Comment: thanks @Bergi, that is exactly the information I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I believe it should look like:

```
Meteor.users.deny({
  update: () => true;
});
```

`deny` is a function that receives an object as a parameter. Your code set `deny` to a new function.

Comment: Thanks for replying Eliezer. When I run that code through babel, it still comes out with the function being named update(). This is easy to do in Coffeescript, frustrating to do in ES2015 ...

Comment: You don't even have a problem. Everything works as it's supposed to as happens when you enter the original JS

Comment: read here for more: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/ but you don't have an issue, or you haven't made clear what the issue is. The code will work as it's supposed to. You can give anonymous JS functions names

Comment: I agree the original question was not as clear as it could have been. I have edited it for greater clarity

Comment: What is your problem? An anonymous function having a name shouldn't be an issue. Why is it an issue for you?

Comment: If there are any other folks migrating from Meteor/Coffescript, some Coffescript output cannot be replicated with ES2015. That was the point of this question - to confirm that fact

Comment: @MIkee that was not the point of the question. Post a question about Coffeescript and what your problem is and then someone can help you. What cannot be replicated?